# How to make text entry into table based on clicking an button in forms in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have created a form with  submit buttons on it.

I have entered the data in the text box and then clicked on submit button.But the data is not getting  saved in the table.Also,it is not  showing  any error message. It is not working at all.

```
Private Sub CmdAddNew_Click()
'add data to table
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblemployee(firstname,lastname,Address,city)" & _
" VALUES('" & Me.txtfirstname & "','" & Me.txtlastname & "','" & Me.txtaddress & "','" &   Me.txtcity & "')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Private Sub CmdAddNew_Click()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database, Sqltext As String, iCount As Integer
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Sqltext = "INSERT INTO tblemployee(firstname,lastname,Address,city) " & _
                 "VALUES('" & Me.txtfirstname & "','" & Me.txtlastname & _
                        "','" & Me.txtaddress & "','" & Me.txtcity & "');"
    Debug.Print "SQL statement generated with variables:" & vbCrLf & Sqltext
    dbs.Execute Sqltext, dbFailOnError
        iCount = dbs.RecordsAffected
    Debug.Print "..." & iCount & " row(s) inserted"

End Sub
```

The debug.print messages will print to the immediate window (Ctrl+g) to view from VBA editor, you can delete them if you want to once you have confirmed it's working.

Comment: it's giving an error "index or  primary key cannot contain a null value"

Comment: Okay, this means that we are either not inserting into all of the columns in tblemployee (and at least one of the missing columns is required) or that we have named one or more of the columns incorrectly in the query. Can you compare the SQL query in the debug window to the column names in the table.

Comment: Chris you are correct but now it's showing an error "record is deleted".

Comment: Can you expand on which of my suggestions was correct and what you have done to fix it please.

Comment: I have added another column to tblemployee and modified the query to   Sqltext = "INSERT INTO tblemployee(EmployeeID,firstname,lastname,Address,city) " & _
                 "VALUES('" & Me.EmployeeID & "','" & Me.txtfirstname & "','" & Me.txtlastname & "','" & _
                 Me.txtaddress & "','" & Me.txtcity & "');"

Comment: What datatype is EmployeeID? If it is a number you should loose the single quotes around it. Alternatively, you could make change the table to make EmployeeID an autonumber, then you can leave it out of the SQL and it will be assigned automatically, but if you have data in the table already back it up first incase of issues when you change the data type.

Comment: The datatype of employeeid is text.it has relationships with other tables.